# Why do I need a script loader?

Tags: loader

People are telling me that I need a script loading for web app, but I already have <script /> and <link /> tags already, can anyone tell me when I should use a script or resource loader? and What is the load you recommend.

Comment: What is a script loader?

Comment: Can u tell us a little why would they say that you need to load resources and in what scenario

Comment: @Ash True story. I guess a browser is a script loader then? @ OP, Yes, a browser would be required for a web app, in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming they are referring to loading and executing javascript files as and when needed, to reduce the initial load times of pages by not loading all your scripts in the head section of the html.

Not totally sure if thats what your getting out, could you give more information on the situation? does your web app have a large number of javascript tags?

Answer (score 0):

I think the requirement of the scripts loader is for multiple <script src=""> tags in the html page, one of more of the scripts have the loading order required, like: the jquery.js must be loaded before the jquery-plugin.js. Another case is the scripts which will be loaded are different in different client devices, like the javascript run for desktop client will be different than the javascript run in the touch pad

Answer (score 0):

When you are working on a single-page application with a lot of dependencies between JS files.